# How to handle imbalanced Data set features for classification problems?

Tags: neural-network, classification

I have a Data set with 300 features that are dummies 0 or 1 and two classes for output 0 or 1 and the distribution of classes is 48% and 52%, but the distribution of the features is skewed as in the picture, I use neural network as my classification algorithm but either I get over fitted model with near 100% accuracy on training set and about 58% accuracy on the test set, or I use Early stopping to prevent over fitting and get around 57% accuracy for training and about 54% for testing.
The optimal error for this problem is around 20% so if I at least reach 70% accuracy on the test I am happy, but I cannot even pass the 60% mark, How to deal with that?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me your problem come from your data set imbalance. What is your model ? how do you calibrate it ?